# How to print date with month and day in crontab and redirect to another txt file?

Tags: date, cron

How to   print date with month and day in crontab and redirect to another txt file

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but the answer is fairly straight forward. A crontab file simply holds `shell commands` to execute at a predefined time or recurrence as specified by the time code that precedes the shell command. You create your crontab file with:

```
crontab -e
```

That will open the default editor for your system and `edit/create` a crontab file to run under the current `user` (presumably you). The format of the crontab entry is:

```
* * * * * command_to_execute
| | | | |
| | | | +- day of week  (0-6) (Sunday = 0)
| | | +--- month        (1-12)
| | +----- day of month (1-31)
| +------- hour         (0-23)
+--------- minute       (0-59)
```

You will want to choose a `date +FORMAT` that meets your needs and then simply redirect the output of the command to a text file. For example:

```
10 0 * * * /usr/bin/date "+%b %d" >> /path/to/textfile
```

Will run the `date` command at `10 minutes past midnight` each day and redirect the output `Nov 01` (for today) to the text file `/path/to/textfile`. You will need to confirm on your system the path to the `date` command is `/usr/bin/date` (usually is). Let me know if you have any further questions.